# JQuery sibling selector with multiple types

Tags: javascript, jquery

For instance if I have the following:

```
var siblingIcon = $(elem).siblings('i');
```

That looks at an element and selects all the `<i>` elements on the same level. How can I add to that that if `siblingIcon` doesn't contain anything (because no `<i>` elements were found, to rather look for `<span>` elements?

so..

```
var siblingIcon = $(elem).siblings('i') || $(elem).siblings('span');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`multiple selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) there,

```
var siblingIcon = $(elem).siblings('i,span');
```

The above code will look for both `i` and `span` elements in the siblings level of the `elem`.

Comment: Won't this return `span` regardless of whether there are any `i` elements present or not?

Comment: Yeah it will. But OP didn't mention anything about the criteria like, both`i` and `span` are present as siblings. I hope this is what he's looking for. If not he will comment back or edit his question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the intention is that `span` should only be selected if there is no `i` element.

You can check the size of returned jquery object

```
var siblingIcon = $(elem).siblings('i').size() ? $(elem).siblings('i') :  $(elem).siblings('span');
```

or directly `length`

```
var siblingIcon = $(elem).siblings('i').length ? $(elem).siblings('i') :  $(elem).siblings('span');
```